# "Into darkness" vs "Into the darkness"

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles

I was watching an interview with Zachary Quinto (the actor who plays SPock in the new Star Trek movie Star Trek: Into Darknaess) on Jonathan Ross and Jonathan introduced them in the first minute and he says:

"Into **the** darkness"

And Zachary correct him and say "Into Darkness"

You can watch and hear it here (around 0:45 - 0:55):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfKswyqcwR8

I have made the same mistake when I was searching this movie on piratebay :) and "Into the darkness" gives me just "Elvis Presley - Blazing Into The Darkness" and not the new star trek movie, but then I remove "the" and the results appears ;)

So, my question is why Elvis Presley used "the and they don't and which one is correct one?

I assume that "Into the darkness" is gramatically correct and "Into darkness" is wrong.

Or am I wrong?

Comment: It has nothing to do with *darkness* and everything to do with the definite article. Brush up on the definite article or follow ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: How can I "brush up", if both possibilities are possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'into the darkness' seems to imply that there is some specific darkness that is being entered - 'the darkness of the night', 'the all-consuming darkness of a black hole', 'the darkness of the soul', etc. When the definite article is removed, that phrase has a much less specific meaning; darkness here seems like it conotes the more general things we think of when we say darkness - the darker human emotions, evil, etc. Grammatically, they both work, but I would only use 'into the darkness' if there is a clear indication of what darkness I'm referring to.

Comment: Why the author chose "Into darkness"? Is it more common in the US? Because the show host Jonathan Ross sid it as: "Into the darkness" and the actor corrected him after that to : "Into darkness".

Comment: Perhaps because *Star Trek* is two words, so there's better rhythm to the full title.

Comment: @Derfder Likely because the darkness that is being described in the title isn't really a specific darkness... I'd read it as more of the description of Khan's character as pseudo-evil.